# Erro estranho na linha XLWorkbook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, aplicação-web, webforms

Pessoal me apareceu essa mensagem no meu código que estou postando na imagem, alguém pode me auxiliar em busca de uma solução;

Segue o código:

```
protected void importar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selecionarArquivo.HasFile)
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.FileName) != ".xlsx" && Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.FileName) != ".xls")
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Erro", "<script>alert('Somente arquivos em excel')</script>");
        else
        {
            if (selecionarArquivo.FileContent != null)
            {

                var wb = new XLWorkbook(selecionarArquivo.FileContent);
                var planilha = wb.Worksheet(1);

                var linha = 1;
                while (true)
                {
                    //aqui vc vai pegar os campos que deseja atrave da especificação da Coluna e da Linha
                    var nome = planilha.Cell("A" + 6.ToString()).Value.ToString();
                    break;
                }

                var cont = 1;
                //var ListaAplImportProcesso = new List<AplImportProcesso>();
                foreach (var x in planilha.RowsUsed())
                {
                    ListaAplImportProcesso.Add(new AplImportProcesso
                    {
                        dataDeRequisicaoPgto = Convert.ToDateTime.Cell(cont),
                        NumeroProcessoAnterior = x.Cell(cont + 1).GetString()
                    });
                    cont++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloque o código e o erro ao invés de uma imagem.

Comment: Postei o código ae.

Comment: XLWorkbook é uma classe que voce esta usando ou é um método de uma dll?

Answer (score 0):

Como você não instalou o pacote então você não têm as DLLs apropriadas. Ao não ter essas DLLs você vai receber o erro especificado

> Type or namespace 'XLWorkbook' could not be found.

Em *Solution Explorer* > *References* > Botão direito do *mouse* > *Add Reference* > Menu COM > Procure por Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library (ou menor dependendo do seu Excel).

Comment: já adicionei mas a mensagem do erro ainda continua :/

Comment: @Amaral tentou rebuildar a solução?

Comment: Sim sim, realizei isso, a linha vermelha debaixo do nome XLWorbook sumiu, porém apareceu a linha azul debaixo do XLWorkbook e a mensagem: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'XLWorkbook' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Repositório SVN\SDP\SDPJ\branches\SDPJ-V3.0.0\SDPJView\ImportacaoProcessoView\ImportacaoProcesso.aspx.cs 82 38 SDPJView